# CSS FOOTER for Basic Website

Tags: css, footer

I have a basic website, but I'm trying to put a fixed footer at the bottom similar to what I did for my header. For my header, I did the following.

```
body {
    background: url(blueheader.jpg) repeat-x #F4f4f2
}
```

I want to do the same thing but have it show up at the bottom.

Comment: I highly recommend you to read some basic things about HTML. You want to use elements for this.

Comment: Copy the header css and add in bottom:0 so it appears at the bottom of the screen :)

Comment: If you find my answer helpful (which it should be...) please mark it as correct!

Answer (score 0):

You should be wrapping your header and footer in their own tags and targeting them seperately. Leave the body as the "canvas" for your site.

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="header"></div>
content!
<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: red;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately on this project, I'm being forced to do the code within homestead.com because its for a friend of mine. So right now, in the box that's called <html> Head Tag: I have <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="/header.css">. Then I uploaded a .css file with that original basic code I put below. The answer you gave me looks to give me background colors, but I need Images? So would I just upload the CSS file you have above, but remove background-color, and put the background: url? And then put the HTML code you have above in the HTML insert but still leave my Header tag?

Comment: This is the website I started if it helps. http://dbac.homestead.com/. I basically want the same thing I have for the header, and my footer. I made a separate image, called bg-footer.jpg

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <footer>
    Your content here.
 </footer>
```

CSS:

```
 footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px; /* change this to suit your necessary height */
    background: url(blueheader.jpg) repeat-x #F4f4f2;
 }
```

Comment: No height will confuse the heck out of someone. Also your code won't compile because you have a dangling background selector.

Comment: The commented text refers to adding whatever his background is. And the OP's code doesn't refer to a height for the header, so I didn't bother adding to my answer.  I think you're being a little too critical in an attempt at getting points for your answer.  Not very cool...

Comment: You're right. It wasn't cool of me. My bad. I'll edit your code so he doesn't confuse himself with the background thing.